# Linked server from SQL server on AWS RDS to On premises Oracle database

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, linked-server

We are planning to migrate an on-premises Microsoft SQL server database to AWS RDS SQL server. Everything is good except one roadblock, i.e  this SQL server database has a linked server to on premises Oracle database.
I read in AWS documentation that currently RDS SQL server only supports linked server to other RDS SQL server within same VPC. So how can I create a linked server to an on-premises Oracle database from RDS SQL server?
Can anyone please suggest best alternatives/solutions for this scenario.

Comment: As you point out, RDS only has access to other RDS instances in the same VPC. So if you need to connect to a database that is on prem, you should probably explore solutions other than RDS.